# Barrier for multiple promises / wait for multiple setTimeout calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, settimeout

is was wondering - whats the way to synchronize multiple setTimeout calls. Basically this code should print A, B and C (order doesn't matter) but it's important that Done should be printed last.

```js
function printAsync(s) {
  return new Promise( function(resolve){
       setTimeout(function() {
           console.log(s);
           resolve();
       }, Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+500));
  })
}


function inparallel(parallel_functions, final_function) {
  let p = Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    const promises = [];
    for( i = 0 ; i < parallel_functions.length ; i++) {
      promises.push(parallel_functions[i]); 
    }
     return Promise.all(promises);
  }).then(() => {
    final_function();
  });

}

A=function(){printAsync("A");}
B=function(){printAsync("B");}
C=function(){printAsync("C");}
D=function(){printAsync("Done");}

inparallel([A,B,C],D)
```

Comment: `Promise.all()` seems like all you need here.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like all you need here is `Promise.all()` all by itself and then you need to return the promises from your functions so those promises can be used to coordinate things.

Here's a runnable snippet to illustrate.

You will see a different relative order between "A", "B" and "C" on multiple runs (due to the random timers you use), but "Done" will always be last.

```js
    function printAsync(s) {
      return new Promise( function(resolve){
           setTimeout(function() {
               console.log(s);
               resolve();
           }, Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+500));
      })
    }

    const A = function(){return printAsync("A");}
    const B = function(){return printAsync("B");}
    const C = function(){return printAsync("C");}
    
    const D = function(){return printAsync("Done");}

    Promise.all([A(), B(), C()]).then(D);
```

FYI, I don't see anything in your `inparallel()` implementation that you can't use `Promise.all()` for, but your `inparallel()` can't do it's job because your functions don't return the promises they create.  When you do this:

```
promises.push(parallel_functions[i]());
```

There's no return value from calling `parallel_functions[i]()` so your array that you pass to `Promise.all()` doesn't actually have any promises to operate on.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer, but im still confused what is the difference between promises.push(parallel_functions[i]()) and [A(), B(), C()] - those two arrays consist of values returned by those functions

Comment: @MichałDygas - I'm noticing that this is from 5 months ago.  Let me take a minute and try to remember what we were discussing.  When you pass an array to `Promise.all()` that array should be an array of promises.  Your original question did this `promises.push(parallel_functions[i]);`.  That was an array of functions, not an array of promises. Then, when you try to do `promises.push(parallel_functions[i]());` that actually calls the functions, but they have no return value so now you're passing an array of `undefined` values. In your example, you need to call a function that RETURNS a PROMISE.